# Maximal interval of this ODE: $ x'=\frac{t^2}{x^2+t^2} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation

$$
x'=\frac{t^2}{x^2+t^2}
$$

I'm asked whether this equation has sublinear growth and if every maximal solution is defined in $\mathbb{R}$. We have seen in class that, if the domain of the equation is of the form $I\times\mathbb{R}^N$ with $I$ an open interval and there is sublinear growth, then the maximal interval is $I$. In this case, the domain of this equation is $D=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \left\lbrace(0,0)\right\rbrace$ and I don't know how to proceed:

- I think that $f(t,x)=\frac{t^2}{x^2+t^2} \ \forall (t,x) \in D$ is sublinear. If $t=0, \ |f(t,x)|=0\leq 1$, and if $t\neq 0, \ |f(t,x)|=\frac{t^2}{x^2+t^2}\leq\frac{t^2}{t^2}=1$, so in both cases $|f(t,x)|\leq 1$.
- The domain is different, so I can't apply this result. I read the proof in case I could change something but it was based on a corollary which required the domain to be of the form $I\times\mathbb{R}^N$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not an expert, but you can consider $(0, +\infty) \times \Bbb R$ and $(-\infty, 0) \times \Bbb R$ separately, then try to glue the solutions that have $x \not = 0$ at $t = 0$.